# Running startup on elasticsearch using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch

I am trying to run the code below:
`// on startup

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));

// on shutdown

client.close();`

I want to ask , where do i run the code on the elasticsearch packages?
I moved it to eclipse, I want to know where is it(on the code it is mentioned on startup and on shutdown.

Comment: Please read the rules about formatting, and make your post readable.

Comment: What I need to change exactly?